# Best method of displaying an alternative on javascript crash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im looking for a very general method of providing an alternative site to a Javascript heavy site (a link going to the old static site).

My current implementation is:

```
//<Some JS/HTML>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //<Some JS Code>
    $('#error').attr('style','display: none;');
});
//<Some html>
<div id="error">
        <span>If you can see this, that means something went very very wrong. Click <a href="somelink.php">Here</a> to use the old portal. Please contact some@email.com with this error and provide as much information as possible, thank you :) </span>
</div>
```

My current problem is that this is visible while the site is loading :(. Is there a better method?

I know i can try and add lots of trys and catchs (theres already several), but the problem is the primary clients are going to be using a mixture of clients between. FF2-FF3, all version in between, and IE5-IE6. The IE5 im just placing a messagebox and redirection if they try to load the site, im not even going to try and make that compatible.

And these old browsers just are not compatible with certain things.... I know i could add in an .onerror, but FF didn't add compatibility until FF6 which is to new for most of the clients. (although strangely, IE5.5 has it)

NOTE: Im just jQuery 1.7.1
The basic flow of the current operation is just when it finishes loading the initial javascript it hides the div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use mainly CSS with a JS helper for this.

Put this JS code as close to the top of the document as you dare, preferibly after the charset declaration. You will need to include jQuery before this line or you can use standard JS (`document.getElementByID('html-tag').className='js';`, this assumes you've given the `html` tag an id of `html-tag`):

```
$('html').addClass('js');
```

Then you can write your CSS to take into account the fact that JS may or may not be available:

```
#error {
    display : block;/*if no JavaScript is available then show this element*/
}
.js #error {
    display : none;/*if JavaScript is available then hide this element*/
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x4tjL/ (JSFiddle seems to be having problems right now, here is a JSBin: http://jsbin.com/ahezuc/edit#preview)

### Update

Putting the JavaScript code as near the top of the document and not wrapping the code in a `document.ready` event handler allows you to minimize the "flash" of content that is common when trying to hide/show content based on JS.

Comment: Part of what's implied here is that by leaving the document.ready() constraint this JS can execute much earlier.

Comment: @EBarr Thanks EBarr, looks like I omitted that important piece of information from my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this did work excellently, although i added it in the .ready function because i was under the impression that it would be executing it to early at that stage. And the comilation error wouldn't occur. I know modern browsers have JIT compiling, but the older browsers don't.... So would it be an issue at all or am i just noobing it> :P

Comment: @Mattisdada I can't give you a 100% answer on that. But generally if you place JS code after the element you are trying to select, you will be able to select the element. That being said, if you are running the code inside a `document.ready` event handler and you don't notice a flash of content, then you might as well keep it there.

Comment: Thanks :) You've all been very helpful

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to detect all incompatible browsers and show the message to upgrade their browser or to redirect to non js site, something like:

```
for IE5 and 6
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 6){
    //show my message here
}
```

Comment: Thats already done, its the odd versions of Firefox that seem to be the issue, under my own testing, the latest version of FF2 and FF3 are alright, its some of the odd version of FF that are causing the primary source of issues..... (and also, from the clients getting the issue they aren't forthcoming with knowledge....)